# How to compile s-expression at runtime and then execute it in Common Lisp

Tags: common-lisp, runtime-compilation

I am working on a program that generates program (Genetic Programming). I build at runtime an s-expression and today I use eval like this:

```
(defvar *program* '(+ x 1))
(defvar x 10)
(eval *program*) ;; returns 11
```

Evaluation is done for multiple x and I want to compile the s-expression into a function at runtime and then call it for multiple x to improve performance.

I can't figure out how to do it and I will appreciate some help. Here is what I have:

```
;;;; This is not working code
(defmacro compile-program (args &body body)
  (compile nil `(lambda (,@args)
                  (declare (ignorable ,@args))
                  (progn ,@body))))

(funcall (compile-program (x) *program*) 10) ;; returns (+ X 1)
(funcall (compile-program (x) (+ x 1)) 10) ;; returns 11
```

**Edit:**
Thx to @RainerJoswig I made the following modifications and it works:

```
;;;; Working Code
(defvar *program* '(+ x 1))

(defun compile-program (args program)
  (compile nil `(lambda ,args
                   (declare (ignorable ,@args))
                    ,program)))

(funcall (compile-program '(x) *program*) 10) ;; returns 11
```

Comment: COMPILE-PROGRAM should not be a macro. Your macro also has an argument PROGRAM which you don't use. You use an undefined variable BODY. Anyway, start with a function.

Comment: @RainerJoswig Thx for your advice. I fixed the undefined body variable, it was a mistake when editing the question.

Comment: but it is still a macro, why?

Comment: @RainerJoswig I was using a macro so I did not have to quote the args, but now I realize It was not what I wanted. Thx for your help.

Comment: This looks better. You can also remove the `progn`. It's not needed.

Comment: `(,@args)` is the same as `,args`

Answer (score 2):

Thx to @RainerJoswig and @coredump I made the following modifications and it works:

```
;;;; Working Code
(defvar *program* '(+ x 1))

(defun compile-program (args program)
  (compile nil `(lambda ,args
                   (declare (ignorable ,@args))
                    ,program)))

(funcall (compile-program '(x) *program*) 10) ;; returns 11
```